# Access a Named Control Inside a XAML DataTemplate

Tags: c#, uwp

I managed to access control in the datatemplate of a GridViewItem, the following code:

```
private void btnChangePhoneNumber_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GridCell.SelectedItem = GridCell.Items[3];
        var container = GridCell.ContainerFromIndex(3);
        var _children = AllChildren(container);
        var _control = _children.First(c => c.Name == "PhoneNumber");
        _control.text = "123456789";
    }


public List<TextBlock> AllChildrenText(DependencyObject parent)
    {
        var _List = new List<TextBlock> { };
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
        {
            var _Child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            if (_Child is TextBlock)
            {
                _List.Add(_Child as TextBlock);
            }

            _List.AddRange(AllChildrenText(_Child));
        }
        return _List;
    }
```

where the GridCell is a Gridview.

This work.. but..

If I implement `GridView` with less than 40 items it's all right.
Unlike if I implement `gridView` with 10000 items, the text change that happens with the method: `btnChangePhoneNumber_Click`, also happens in other items ... and I can not understand the reason since, in the `btnChangePhoneNumber_Click` method, only one item is chosen.

Thanks in advance. A greeting.

Comment: A question: What does your DataTemplate look like? Are you using bindings? If so, you're most likely breaking the bindings when explicitly setting the text in codebehind. This affects other items as you scroll as the DataTemplate will be recycled and reused as it moves out of view to improve performance. Either switch to x:Bind in your DataTemplate which will avoid bindings be broken, or update the bound value directly in the model instead of the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code, but I could not reproduce your issue in my side. As far as I'm concerned, It is low performance to render 10000 items in your `GridView`. And using `VisualTreeHelper` will bring about worse performance. You could bind
the text of `TextBlock` in the datatemplate with mvvm ViewModel. You just need 
to modify the view model and the text of `TextBlock` will be changed. For more please refer to [Data binding in depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth). And the following is segment code of ViewModel.

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Phone> _items;
    public ObservableCollection<Phone> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        var list = new ObservableCollection<Phone>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new Phone { PhoneNumber = "123456" });
        }
        _items = list;
    }

}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel"/>
</Page.DataContext>
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Click="btnChangePhoneNumber_Click" Content=" click me"/>
    <GridView x:Name="GridCell" Height="400" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Phone">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind PhoneNumber ,Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</StackPanel>
```

I have upload the [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/GridViewTest.git) to github. Please check!

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I wanted!